# Css table column width "as is"

Tags: html, css, width, css-tables

Is there any way to specify table column width "as is". In other words, I want a column to have exact width its content takes to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be the default case.

```
<!-- "table-layout" is "auto" by default as well, just to force it -->
<table border="1" style="table-layout:auto;">
    <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[This is how it looks like](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4254118/table.html)